# It's the Friday before Dreamforce. Ya'll excited?

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

Yup, this question isn't very constructive.  It should probably be closed. ✌(◕‿-)✌

Comment: This would be a welcome post on meta. You might want to try posting these tangentially related "questions" there.

Comment: +100000 up votes!!!

Answer (score 5):

No because I'm not going [image]

Comment: Eight years going where I won't be able to make it either. I'm really disappointed, too. I would have thought this many years of developing would have meant something.

Comment: But on the upside, its a chance to get some points on SFSE while all the other top point earners (except sfdcfox) are at DreamForce

Comment: At this point, I'm just 200 points behind second place, so many I can sneak up from behind! But I'd rather be at Dreamforce...

Comment: Great achievement for only 5 months on here. You will be in first place soon enough. If you give me 10,000 points I will give you a ticket to DreamForce, some magic beans and $1,000,000 from a Nigerian Prince.

Comment: We should fully be able to exchange imaginary internet points for goods and services. 5000 points to the person who can make this happen [Run anonymous apex as if it were a test case](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000inJZAAY)

Comment: You guys should totally submit some abstracts next year, get to talk and get a free ticket! That said there are other costs of course, but a free ticket might help sway those who hold the purse strings?